# Disable All Authentication Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an API written in Django, with authentication with cookie and sessionid.

Now I want to add a end-point public, with any kind of authentication, but I can't access the end-point.

What I've done:

## URL:

```
 url(r'^api/public_end_point/?$', csrf_exempt(views.publicEndPoint.as_view()), name='public_end_point')
```

## Views:

```
class publicEndPoint(APIView):

    @api_view(['POST'])
    @permission_classes([permissions.AllowAny,])
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):


        return Response({"success": True, "content": "Hello World!"})
```

Some Ideas about what am I missing here ?

Thanks

## EDIT

Settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    # MY MIDDLEWARE #
    'config.middleware.EnforceLoginMiddleware',
    'config.middleware.AuditMiddleware',
    'config.middleware.ExceptionMiddleware',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',),
    'PAGE_SIZE': 20
}

[15/Feb/2017 15:57:16] "POST /api/public_end_point HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[15/Feb/2017 15:57:16] "GET /sign/base.html?nu=/api/public_end_point HTTP/1.1" 200 2906
```

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I get a 302- Redirect

Comment: @DanielRoseman I edited my post with more details

Answer (score 0):

Just add `PERMISSION_CLASSES = (,)` to your view as class variable, you don't need to use a decorator.

Just for informational purposes - Django Rest Framework by default uses `BasicAuthentication` and `SessionAuthentication` such that you either need to be logged in or provide Basic authentication credentials to access the api.

If you need your own custom token authentication, you need to override `AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` in your drf settings.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
     # add your own authentication class   
    )
}
```

Comment: I want to keep my API as it is, except on this end-point I want it public

Comment: I still get redirect : [15/Feb/2017 15:57:16] "POST /api/public_end_point HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[15/Feb/2017 15:57:16] "GET /sign/base.html?nu=/api/public_end_point HTTP/1.1" 200 2906

Comment: Remove all decorators you are using on POST method

Comment: class publicEndPoint(generics.GenericAPIView):
    PERMISSION_CLASSES = ()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'test'
        return Response({"success": True, "content": "Hello World!"})

Comment: is like this. removed decorators,, added the class variable

Comment: This should work, don't forget to add a comma in permission classes tuple though